# Write an Annotation Processor to make all method args FINAL

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, final

I am trying to an annotation processor to implicitly make particular method(annotated) arguments final?

My Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MakeFinal_Args {

}
```

and my annotation processor looks like this:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.walmart.annotations.MakeFinal_Args")
public class Processor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private ProcessingEnvironment env;

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Class<?> clazz = Runtime.getRuntime().getClass();

        for (Parameter parameter : clazz.getEnclosingMethod().getParameters()) {
            parameter.
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Stuck here.Need help with the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Curious:* Why is RetentionPolicy `RUNTIME`? Changing method to `final` should be done at *compile-time*, so compilation of subclasses will fail if they try to override the method. As such, the annotation is not needed at *runtime*.

Comment: This cannot be done with an annotation processor. Annotation processors are only capable of generating new code. To edit the bytecode structure of code being currently compiled you would have to create a compiler plugin.

Comment: @Andreas Its not about changing method to final but the method args to final .

Comment: @vandench I am trying it now. Will update you in a while.

Comment: @ShreyasMN I stand corrected, but it doesn't change the fact that the annotation is for the compiler, and is not needed at runtime.